# How to listen for child event from parent directive in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a child component 'my-component' which is wrapped by a Directive 'MyDirective' , I need to emit an event to parent directive from the child component, I know how to do it for parent component using @Output but no luck with directive.

```
<div myDirective >
    <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use a template variable and reference it in an event handler:

```
<div myDirective #mydir>
    <my-component (someEvent)="mydir.someMethod()"></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, Is there any other approach if myDirective is a structural directive ?

Comment: Hmm, I guess I would need a concrete example. Can you create a Plunker that demonstrates what you try to accomplish? You could also use `dispatchEvent()` to fire a DOM event. DOM events bubble and you can listen to it using `<div myDirective (someEvent)="someMethod()">`. There are often many ways to skin a cat ;-) It usually depends on the details what approach is a better fit.

Comment: <div myDirective>
       <my-component></my-component>
       <my-component></my-component>
       <my-component></my-component>
       <my-component></my-component>
   </div>


my-component has two methods, up() and down(), 
say if someone clicks on the 3rd my-component, I want to 
call show() of 3rd my-component and call hide() of all other 
my-component components, via myDirective directive.

Comment: `<my-component (click)="showIdx=3" [hidden]="showIdx!==3"` The same for other component but with different number for each. If this isn't what you want please add it to your question with more code that makes it obvious what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but this is not the solution I'm after, there must be a structural directive, everything should handled within that directive, my-component should emit an event..

Comment: Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. "structural directive" isn't really information that I can worke with.